# SAP GUI Script & VBA: Get System Name / ID

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have already created a gui scripting to automate some task. Now, there is a part where I needed to get the SAP system ID / Name. I need get the system ID / Name where the user is currently logged on.

Currently I am using Q4N. So far below is my Code:

```
Dim app As Variant      
Dim SAPGUIAuto As Object 
Dim Connection As Variant 
Dim session As Variant
Dim MainPage as Worksheet
set MainPage = Sheets("Main")

If Not IsObject(app) Then
Set SAPGUIAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set app = SAPGUIAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
Set Connection = app.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
WScript.ConnectObject app, "on"
End If

Set Info = session.Info()

MainPage.Range("E22") = Val(Info.SystemName())
```

I tried to display this Info.SystemName() but it gives me zero number.

I also tried recording a script in order to get this info:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no recorded step for me to be able to get the system ID.

Comment: http://codezentrale.bplaced.net/dcz/?p=7221

Comment: Thanks Storax! Tried it and was able to get the system name. I will try to incorporate this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Function ConexionScriptSap() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo miError
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI") 'Conexión con sesión activa de SAP
       Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Conexión con sesión activa de SAP
       Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Conexión con sesión activa de SAP
       Set session = SAPCon.Children(0) 'Conexión con sesión activa de SAP
       System = Split(session.PassportPreSystemId, "/")(0)
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    ConexionScriptSap = True
    Exit Function
    
miError:
    'MsgBox "Error en la conexión al SAP"
    Err.Description = "Sin conexion SAP"
    ConexionScriptSap = False
End Function
```

So, in your Main Process you can add this validation.

```
If System = "PR3" Or System = "QR3" Then
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

As the link from my comment is gone you can go to
https://web.archive.org/web/20171214232049/http://codezentrale.bplaced.net/dcz/?p=7221

Here is the relevant code from the link above

```
Option Explicit

Sub SAP()
    Dim oSapGui As Object
    ' Extras -> Verweise ... -> Durchsuchen ...
    ' C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfewse.ocx
    ' Aktivieren: SAP GUI Scripting API
    Dim oApp As SAPFEWSELib.GuiApplication
    Dim oConn As SAPFEWSELib.GuiConnection
    Dim oSession As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession
    Dim oSessionInfo As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSessionInfo
    Dim oWindow As SAPFEWSELib.GuiMainWindow
    Dim oComponent As SAPFEWSELib.GuiComponent
    Dim oSubComponent As SAPFEWSELib.GuiComponent
    
    Debug.Print "----------"
    
    ' Ref auf SAPGUI
    Set oSapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    If IsObject(oSapGui) Then
        ' Ref auf ScriptingEngine
        Set oApp = oSapGui.GetScriptingEngine
        If IsObject(oApp) Then
            
            Debug.Print oApp.ID
            Debug.Print oApp.Name
            
            ' Liste Connections
            For Each oConn In oApp.Children
                Debug.Print "|--" & oConn.ConnectionString
                Debug.Print "|  " & oConn.Description
                Debug.Print "|  " & oConn.ID
                Debug.Print "|  " & oConn.Name
                
                ' Sessions sind nur verfügbar, wenn RZ11 Parameter sapgui/user_scripting = TRUE
                ' Liste Sessions
                For Each oSession In oConn.Children
                    Debug.Print "  |--" & oSession.ID
                    Debug.Print "  |  " & oSession.Busy
                    
                    ' Ref auf Session Info
                    Set oSessionInfo = oSession.Info
                    
                    If IsObject(oSessionInfo) Then
                        Debug.Print "    |--" & oSessionInfo.SystemSessionId
                        Debug.Print "    |  " & oSessionInfo.ApplicationServer
                        Debug.Print "    |  " & oSessionInfo.SystemName
                        Debug.Print "    |  " & oSessionInfo.Client
                        Debug.Print "    |  " & oSessionInfo.Transaction
                        Debug.Print "    |  " & oSessionInfo.User
                    End If
                    
                    ' Ref auf Fenster
                    For Each oWindow In oSession.Children
                        Debug.Print "      |--" & oWindow.ID
                        Debug.Print "      |  " & oWindow.Text
                        Debug.Print "      |  " & oWindow.Left
                        Debug.Print "      |  " & oWindow.Top
                        Debug.Print "      |  " & oWindow.Width
                        Debug.Print "      |  " & oWindow.Height
                        
                        ' Liste mit Komponenten im Fenster
                        For Each oComponent In oWindow.Children
                            Debug.Print "        |--" & oComponent.ID
                            Debug.Print "        |  " & oComponent.Name
                            Debug.Print "        |  " & oComponent.Type
                            Debug.Print "        |  " & oComponent.ContainerType
                            
                            ' Liste mit Unterkomponenten (können wiederum auch Unterkomponenten haben -> besser rekursiv aufrufen)
                            For Each oSubComponent In oComponent.Children
                                Debug.Print "          |--" & oSubComponent.ID
                                Debug.Print "          |  " & oSubComponent.Name
                                Debug.Print "          |  " & oSubComponent.Type
                                Debug.Print "          |  " & oSubComponent.ContainerType
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
    
    Set oSubComponent = Nothing
    Set oComponent = Nothing
    Set oWindow = Nothing
    Set oSessionInfo = Nothing
    Set oSession = Nothing
    Set oConn = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oSapGui = Nothing
End Sub
```